# problem in variable scope in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket

I use  top of root:

```
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StatusBar key="AppStatusBar" barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor={colors.blackAlertHeader} />
    <Socket />
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>
);
```

I have problem when I send status from redux to this component:

```
const Socket: React.FC<ISocketHandler> = (props: ISocketHandler) => {

let socket: WebSocket;

useEffect(() => {
checkAppState(props.wsStatus.wsStatus);
return () => AppState.removeEventListener('change', () => controlSocketConnection());
}, [props.wsStatus.wsStatus]);


const checkAppState = (status) => {
if (!status) {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', () => controlSocketConnection());
} else if (status == 'wsSignin' || status == 'wsSignout') {
  controlSocketConnection(status);
}
};

const controlSocketConnection = async (status = '') => {
if (AppState.currentState == 'active' && status !== 'wsSignout') {
  socket = await connectToWS();
  getNewState(socket);
} else if (AppState.currentState == 'background' || status == 'wsSignout') {
  socket.close();
}
```

};

I use this component over all of others, so when I send `props.wsStatus.wsStatus= 'wsSignout'` here, it can not access to socket, socket is undefined. how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**
Finally I resolve it with using `const socket= useRef<WebSocket>(null)`. The socket variable keep its value until component isn't unmounted and it's important that changing this don't cause re-render component.

Comment: You never assign `socket` to anything.  Is this an attempt to assign it? `let socket: WebSocket;`  Seems like it's supposed to be `let socket = WebSocket;`

Comment: yeah, when App is active or 'wsSignin', I call `socket = await connectToWS();` to create a socket. when app is active or background, socket is correct, but when I try to wsSignout, `socket` in `socket.close()` is undefined.